# How to configure aspectj in pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, aspectj

In my project I use aspects for logging. When I use `eclipse compiler`, everything works OK, but I have some problems with `Maven`. No logs are displayed - aspects classes aren't "seen".

I've tried to google it, but [apache tutorial](http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/plugins/aspectj/) isn't clear for me. Other tutorials are about `spring`.

What should I add to pom.xml?

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Agent</groupId>
  <artifactId>Agent</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>  
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>  
        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
        <version>1.3</version>  
        <configuration>  
          <complianceLevel>1.5</complianceLevel>  
        </configuration>  
        <executions>  
        </executions>  
      </plugin>  

    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: What kind of problem you get?

Comment: @jddsantaella Using Maven aspectJ classes aren't "seen" - There are no logs. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.If u don't need spring

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.6</source>
                            <target>1.6</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainclass>myproject.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I don't use spring in my project. Should I add this configuration? Where to put it?

Comment: what type of packaging you used